# Linq select statement prints project.class name as result in output console

Tags: c#

I created a class called employees, created three employees. I then created a `List<>` to store the employee objects

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutomationTest
{
    public class Employees
    {
        public String ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Salary { get; set; }

        public static List<Employees> GetEmployeesSalaries()
        {
            List<Employees> employees = new List<Employees>();
            List<int> johnsalary = new List<int> { 1100,1200,1300 };
            List<int> jamessalary = new List<int> { 1400, 1450, 1500 };
            List<int> timsalary = new List<int> { 1600, 1700, 17500 };

            employees.Add(new Employees { ID = "N001", Name = "John", Salary = johnsalary  });
            employees.Add(new Employees { ID = "N002", Name = "James", Salary = jamessalary });    
            employees.Add(new Employees { ID = "N003", Name = "Tim", Salary = timsalary });

            return employees;
        }       
    }  
}
```

I then created the query statement but got the project.class name on the console output as Automationtest.Employee

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
namespace AutomationTest
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Employees> querysalary = (Employees.GetEmployeesSalaries().Where(i => i.Name.Contains("m"))).ToList<Employees>();

            //IEnumerable<Employees> querysalary = from empl in Employees.GetEmployeesSalaries()
            // where empl.Name.Contains("a") select empl;

            //var querysalary = (from k in Employees.GetEmployeesSalaries() select k).ToString();

            foreach (var ss in querysalary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ss);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the default output if you don't override `ToString()`. Either specify what you want to print from the employee, e.g. `$"{ss.Name} (ss.Id)"` in your `Console.WriteLine` call, or override `Employees.ToString()` to return whatever information you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `Console.WriteLine` you are calling the `.toString()` method of the object wich will give you no readable form of the object. You can override it to create your own implementation. Try to add thid function this in your `Employees` Class

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{ID} {Name} {String.Join(", ", Salary)}";
}
```

For the list you have to iterate over the individual entries and put them in a string. This can be done with the `String.Join` method.

Working example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var character = new Employee();
        Console.Write(character);
    }

public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Salary = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{String.Join(", ", Salary)}";
        }

        public List<int> Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, i think i am almost there. its now outputting as below.

Comment: N002 James System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
N003 Tim System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Comment: how do i get rid of the System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]??

Comment: @Elvis don`t forget to mark the answer when your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Hi guys, just to explain that i am new in programming thats why i keep asking this questions. if the run the below query to access the values of the list Salary, i get the below results as before

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Comment: IEnumerable<Employees> querrysalary = from empl in Employees.GetEmployeesSalaries()
                                                 from salary in empl.Salary
                                                  where salary > 1000
                                                  select empl;

           

            foreach (var ss in querrysalary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ss.Salary);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: hmm, on my machine it works... I will update the answer with an example

Comment: @Elvis did you get the example to work? This is how you do it, there must be an error on your side. It looks like you are having lists inside a list, somehow...